# VSC Oracle extension, stop break lines in result window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Extension in VS Code
*Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code (SQL and PLSQL)* from Oracle Corportation

It is possible to turn off breaking lines in random places in Result window?

```
 open c_in_data;
  loop
    fetch c_in_data into r_in_data;
    exit when c_in_data%notfound;
    v_package_spec := v_package_spec || lower(r_in_data.text);   
  end loop; 
  close c_in_data;

  dbms_output.put_line(a  => v_package_spec /*in varchar2*/);
```

and getting results that looks like:
[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0688n.png)

in SQL Developer it looks normal:
[SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNVzv.png)

I,m try to set editor word wrap setting in all possible options.

I want to get window with results in one line per dbms_output, like in SQL Developer.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable test case instead of psuedo code? That would really help.